# Newtonsoft Json Converter converts int to string

Tags: c#, json.net

I am reading data from Oracle database into a data table, convert it to JSON and it seems it converts an int that is 1335 in data table row to "1335.0" which causes issue when deserializing.

The columns is defined in database as:

```
REQUEST_ID      NUMBER(20,0)
```

The (partial) query looks like:

```
SELECT req.REQUEST_ID AS \"uniqueId\",
```

I call an API that returns the result of this query into a C# data table:

```
DataTable dt = ODCException.GetError();
```

When I inspect the rows of "dt", I see uniqueId as 1335, 1336, etc.

I have also defined a class to hold each individual object as:

```
public class jsonObject
{
    public int uniqueId { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

When I serialize "dt":

```
string JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
```

and inspect JSONresult I see:

```
[{"uniqueId":1335.0,...}, {"uniqueId":1336.0,...}]
```

And later, when I try to deserialize:

```
List<jsonObject> loErrorData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<jsonObject>>(JSONresult).ToList();
```

I get:

```
{"Input string '1335.0' is not a valid integer. Path '[0].uniqueId', line 1, position 19."}
```

I need to be able to get the result where "uniqueId" is int and not string.

**Update**

I managed to fix the issue as follows. Even though the column in question is declared in database as NUMBER(28,0), i.e., no decimal point, I kept ending up with "1335.0" instead of 1335 for "uniqueId" column.

So:

```
public static DataTable GetTCErrors()
{
    DataSet ds = oRespository.GetErrors();  // Get data from DB
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        dt2.Columns.Add("uniqueId", typeof(Int32));
        dt2.Load(dt.CreateDataReader(), LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
    }
    return dt2;
}
```

Now, when I use the following, I get 1335, 1336, ... as uniqueId values in JSONresult:

```
DataTable dt = ODCException.GetTCErrors();
string JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the decimal?

Comment: [I can't reproduce your issue](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RkGcvY) with the information you've provided. Please [edit] your post with a [mre].

Comment: `JsonConvert` will not serialize an `int` with a decimal point. Please show a fiddle demonstrating the problem. Possibly `dt` is actually a `DataTable` not a `jsonObject`?

Comment: What is `dt`? What type is it? `DataTable`? Please show how do you get data from the database?

Comment: @mxmissile I cannot remove the decimal, it is what JsonConvert returns.

Comment: @gunr2171 I created a fiddle but can't reproduce! https://dotnetfiddle.net/OgG6py, Not sure where to look for the issue. I updated the question too.

Comment: Can whoever closed this re-open it since I edited the question and included a link to fiddle? I need help to get this issue resolved.

Comment: @Charlieface answered my intention of removing the decimal, there is your answer.

Comment: Here is your repro https://dotnetfiddle.net/9RbgPb I've voted to reopen. The solution is basically to change the query so it reads `SELECT CAST(req.REQUEST_ID AS int) AS uniqueId`

Comment: Not sure what to say, really. I have shown the database column being declared as (NUMBER), the dataset resulting from query shows int values for "uniqueId" as 1335 and 1336. And just after JsconConvert.Serialize I end up with "1335.0" and "1336.0". As you see in the fiddle I posted, I cannot reproduce it in the fiddle which makes it more frustrating. Just not sure where to look for the issue.

Comment: My repro link shows that a column typed as `decimal` wil cause this error. If the column is stored as `NUMBER` in the database then it will be translated to `decimal` not `int` on the C# side so you need to cast.

Comment: @Charlieface thank you. Casting in Oracle query did not help, same error. Also, in Oracle that column is already NUMBER(28,0), no decimal points. Your fiddle point to the fact that deserializing to list of objects where "uniqueId" is defined as int throws error. I don't understand how a datatable column value that is an int (1335) gets converted to "1335.0" once JsonConvert.Serialize is called.

Comment: I found a workaround that solved the issue. I added to "Update" portion of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the column is declared `NUMERIC(28,0)` doesn't get it converted to `int` on the C# side. Only if it's an `INTEGER` then it will be.

So you can just cast it in Oracle

```sql
SELECT CAST(req.REQUEST_ID AS INTEGER) AS "uniqueId",
```

Having said that, your other option is to cast it on the C# side. You have already provided one way of doing that, by first adding the column with `typeof(int)` to the `DataTable`.

But to be honest, if you are creating an object model then you should just forgo the `DataTable` and use the reader directly.

```cs
public static List<jsonObject> GetTCErrors()
{
    var list = new List<jsonObject>();
    using var conn = new OracleConnection(YourConnString);
    using var comm = new OracleCommand(YourQuery, conn);
    // parameters here
    conn.Open();
    using var reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        list.Add(new jsonObject
        {
            uniqueId = (int)(decimal)reader["uniqueId"],  // notice the double-cast
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

You can also use Dapper to do most of this automatically, although I'm not sure how it handles casting like this.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I should have done that in the first place and save myself a lot of grief. The output of all of this is going to Kafka broker and they require the data to be in JSON format. When I do this in Oracle 19c+, I simply use json_object and it is done. It is with pre-19c Oracle that I have to do this JSON conversion manually.

Comment: I used your method of using reader instead of dataset. Marked your response as answer. Thanks for the help.